# Preventing sending some trace logs to Azure with Open-telemetry

Tags: python, django, azure, logging, azure-application-insights

I'm sending logs to Azure AppInsights by using Open-telemetry. The library keeps sending trace data constantly not only when the log occurs as shown in the picture. Is there an any way to close this or prevent it to write on trace table?

```
Request URL: 'https://westeurope-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com//v2.1/track'
Request method: 'POST'
Request headers:
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     'Content-Length': '3039'
     'Accept': 'application/json'
     'x-ms-client-request-id': 'd0b9e1ec-8e1e-11ee-9aaf-0242ac120005'
     'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-azuremonitorclient/unknown Python/3.10.13 (Linux-6.3.13-linuxkit-aarch64-with-glibc2.36)'
A body is sent with the request
Response status: 200
Response headers:
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
    'X-Content-Type-Options': 'REDACTED'
    'Strict-Transport-Security': 'REDACTED'
    'x-request-id': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Tue, 28 Nov 2023 18:49:09 GMT'
Transmission succeeded: Item received: 3. Items accepted: 3
Request URL: 'https://westeurope-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com//v2.1/track'
Request method: 'POST'
Request headers:
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    'Content-Length': '3040'
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '04842826-8df6-11ee-979c-0242ac120005'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-azuremonitorclient/unknown Python/3.10.13 (Linux-6.3.13-linuxkit-aarch64-with-glibc2.36)'
A body is sent with the request
```

[image]

In Django app settings.py

```
logger_provider = LoggerProvider()
set_logger_provider(logger_provider)
exporter = AzureMonitorLogExporter.from_connection_string(
    os.environ["AZURE_MONITOR_EXPORTER_CONNECTION_STRING"]
)
get_logger_provider().add_log_record_processor(BatchLogRecordProcessor(exporter))

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

LOGGING Configuration

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s"  # noqa
        },
        "socotra-request": {
            "format": "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s\n%(message)s\n- - -\n"
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
        "azure": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "opentelemetry.sdk._logs.LoggingHandler",
        },
    },
    "root": {
        "handlers": ["azure", "console"],
        "level": "DEBUG",
    },
}
```

Comment: could you please provide the code you tried? could you tell what type of logs do want to Prevent??

Comment: I just added the code that I used, the types of log I want to prevent is shown in the picture. I guess it belongs to library itself @sampath

Comment: Logs screenshot In text  format also

Comment: I just updated @sampath

Comment: <sarcasm> Why would you want to prevent sending any logs to Azure? Citizens have nothing to hide from the Big Brother!

Comment: Place the project name  in project name ```projectname.filters.ExcludeTraceLogsFilter```

Answer (score 1):

Using this reference [DOC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue) added logging configuration using the `logging`sets up a logger with different levels and filters.

- The custom filter `ExcludeTraceLogsFilter` is defined to exclude log records containing the word "trace" in their messages. Configuring OpenTelemetry to use Azure Monitor for tracing.
- The `configure_azure_monitor` function is invoked with the Azure Application Insights connection string and logging is applied.

[image]

```py
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Custom filter to exclude trace logs
class ExcludeTraceLogsFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return "trace" not in record.getMessage().lower()

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'exclude_trace_logs': {
            '()': 'projectname.filters.ExcludeTraceLogsFilter',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'azure': {  # Adjust the logger name accordingly
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'WARNING',  # Set to WARNING or higher
            'propagate': False,
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['exclude_trace_logs'],
        },
    },
}
```

```py
# filters.py
import logging

class ExcludeTraceLogsFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return "trace" not in record.getMessage().lower()
```

```py
# wsgi.py or manage.py

from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.django import DjangoInstrumentor
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.logging import LoggingInstrumentor

# Configure OpenTelemetry to use Azure Monitor with the specified connection string
configure_azure_monitor(
    connection_string="Azure Application Insights connection_string",
    resource_detectors=[],
)

# Get a tracer for the current module
tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)

# Instrument Django app
DjangoInstrumentor().instrument()

# Instrument logging to capture spans
LoggingInstrumentor().instrument()
```

**Local:**
[image]

[image]

**Azure:**
[image]

[image]